# Обратная связь в Django для ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-orm

У меня есть две таблицы в БД:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Task(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Задача: {}, статус: {}".format(self.name, self.status)
```

Мне нужно получить на одной странице все "Проекты" со связанными с ними "Задачами". Например:

```
Проект1 - Задача1, Задача2; Проект2 - Задача1, Задача2;
```

Я пробовал следующее:

```
projects = Project.objects.all().prefetch_related('task_set')

for project in projects:

    print("project", project.__dict__)
```

Вывод:

```
project `{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x03BEC870>, 'id': 2, 'name': 'Расписание на день', '_prefetched_objects_cache': {'task': <QuerySet [<Task: Задача: Встать в 6:00, статус: False>]>}}`
```

Все вроде работает, выполняются два запроса к БД и берутся нужные данные. Но в шаблоне я не могу (не пойму), как получить связанные с `Project` объекты `Task`.

Я могу просто сделать два запроса:

```
projects = Project.objects.all()
tasks = Task.objects.all()
```

И в шаблоне отфильтровать "Задачи" под каждый "Проект", но если нужно будет, например, брать не все "Проекты", то выйдет, что с БД будут браться ненужные записи "Задач".

Можно ли получить доступ к элементу `_prefetched_objects_cache` из шаблона?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{% for project in projects %}
    {{ project }}
    {% for task in project.task_set.all %}
        {{ task }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```